# BPS BPMN 2.0 support?

Tags: wso2, bpmn

I asked a question a while back about WSO2 support for our BPMN 2.0 support.

It was suggested at the time that this was on the road map. However, I still can't find any details regarding this on the WSO2 site.......

I can't believe this is not currently being worked on ? or even released by now...

There is no way we want to have to convert our BPMN 2.0 processes into BPEL, this is going backwards as far as we are concerned.

So, anybody got any idea if and when we can expect BPMN 2.0 native support in WSO2 ?

Steve

Answer (score 1):

BPMN 2.0 support is on the road map for BPS but however due to other obligations and restrictions BPS team has not been able to allocate time to complete work on BPMN. This is still in the road map and will be released with future releases but it is not possible to give an exact time frame as of now. May be 3 months down the road.